# 'SignInScheme' option must be provided

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, facebook-authentication

I'm creating an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 app that will use Facebook/Google authentication only. I'm also trying to use the cookie middleware without the whole ASP.NET Identity -- following this article:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html

So I started with an blank app with no authentication then added the Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies and Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook NuGet packages in order to have a very minimalistic approach where I don't include anything that I don't need.

I added the following code into Configure in Startup.cs but I'm getting "SignInScheme option must be provided" error. Any idea what I'm missing?

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance";
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Accounts/Login/");
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Error/Unauthorized/");
                options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
                options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
            });

            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = "myFacebookAppIdGoesHere";
                options.AppSecret = "myFacebookAppSecretGoesHere";
            });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As indicated by the error message you're seeing, you need to set `options.SignInScheme` in your Facebook middleware options:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options => {
    options.AppId = "myFacebookAppIdGoesHere";
    options.AppSecret = "myFacebookAppSecretGoesHere";

    // This value must correspond to the instance of the cookie
    // middleware used to create the authentication cookie.
    options.SignInScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance";
});
```

Alternatively, you can also set it globally from `ConfigureServices` (it will configure every authentication middleware so you don't have to set `options.SignInScheme`):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        // This value must correspond to the instance of the cookie
        // middleware used to create the authentication cookie.
        options.SignInScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance";
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. A follow up question: is "MyCookieMIddlewareInstance" the name of my cookie? I'll have to create a temp cookie for the user to register after he gets authenticated by Facebook/Google. Do I then use a different cookie name? If so, where do I set that cookie name?

Comment: No, `AuthenticationScheme` has no influence on the cookie name, it's a purely internal identifier. To change the cookie name, you can use the `CookieName` property.

Comment: In case you have not set up an explicit AuthenticationScheme it's CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme