# ASP.NET Core MVC migration to 2.0: The SignInScheme for a remote authentication handler cannot be set to itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm migrating an ASP.NET Core MVC application from version 1.0.2 to 2.0.
I have in this application an external authentication via Facebook.
When I'm launching the web application I'm facing to this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The SignInScheme for a remote authentication handler cannot be set to itself. If it was not explicitly set, the AuthenticationOptions.DefaultSignInScheme or DefaultScheme is used.

I searched [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) but it did not help me for now.
In my Startup.cs, the method "ConfigureServices" looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // If you want to tweak Identity cookies, they're no longer part of IdentityOptions.
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn");
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = Configuration["AuthenticationFacebookSettings:AppId"];
                options.AppSecret = Configuration["AuthenticationFacebookSettings:AppSecret"];
                options.SignInScheme = "Facebook";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });

        services.Configure<AuthenticationFacebookSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationFacebookSettings"));
        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
                    .
                    .
            // my services
                    .
                    .
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    }
```

The method "Configure" looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

I am missing something here because everything looks alright...
I spend a lot of time on this issue and I am clueless...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34655514/2084315) should answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link of [@ps2goat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084315/ps2goat) put me on right way.
I changed my Facebook options like this (by taking the default value):

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = Configuration["AuthenticationFacebookSettings:AppId"];
                options.AppSecret = Configuration["AuthenticationFacebookSettings:AppSecret"];
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
```

In fact with .NET Core 2.0 migration, I had to change the `SignInScheme`. In my case I did set it to the default value with:

```cs
options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

More precisely, for launching the application it was not enough.
I had to update my view for using "**GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()**" method instead of "**GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes()**" method of the signin manager.

After adapting a little bit my code, it finally works. Thanks [@ps2goat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084315/ps2goat).